# ImportError: No module named 'yolo_utils'

Tags: python-3.5

I downloaded openCV and YOLO weights, in order to implement object detection for a certain project using Python 3.5 version.

when I run this code:

```python
from yolo_utils import read_classes, read_anchors, generate_colors, preprocess_image, draw_boxes, scale_boxes

from yad2k.models.keras_yolo import yolo_head, yolo_boxes_to_corners, preprocess_true_boxes, yolo_loss, yolo_body
```

The console gives the error below:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from yolo_utils import read_classes, read_anchors, generate_colors, preprocess_image, draw_boxes, scale_boxes
>         2 from yad2k.models.keras_yolo import yolo_head, yolo_boxes_to_corners, preprocess_true_boxes, yolo_loss, yolo_body
>
> ImportError: No module named 'yolo_utils'

Note that i downloaded yolo_utils.py in the weights folder, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the source code of [yolo_utils](https://github.com/iArunava/YOLOv3-Object-Detection-with-OpenCV/blob/master/yolo_utils.py) .

Paste it in your source code before importing yolo_utils.

It worked for me.
Hope this will help..

Answer (score 7):

Actually You are Importing user built module. As Yolo_utils is created by a Coursera coordinators to make things easy, this module is available in only their machines and You are trying to import this in your machine.
Here is github link of module :
https://github.com/JudasDie/deeplearning.ai/blob/master/Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/week3/yolo_utils.py
Save this To your local machine in .py formet
And Copy this file in your lib files of Your application(anaconda or any other)